# C# array index always exceeded

Tags: c#, arrays, indexing

I'm having a very odd problem in C# and I'm not sure what is the cause.  Take a look at the following code snippet:

```
foreach(string bed in bayBeds)
{
    string[] bedProperties = bed.Split(new char[] { '^' });
    if (bedProperties.Length > 0)
    {
        string genderCode = bedProperties[1];
        if (genderCode == "M")
        {
            bedCount = bedCount + bayBeds.Count;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

In this example, the string array bedProperties is tested to see if its length is greater than 0, and if so, element 1 is retrieved.  The problem is that this code *always* generates an out of bounds exception.  I can modify to return bedProperties.Length and it will give me a value such as 3 (which is in fact the number of properties in this object), yet any attempt to get an array element by index (such as bedProperties[1], bedProperties[0], etc.) will **always** give me an out of bounds exception.  ***Always***.  I can't understand why this would be.

Please understand I'm something of a c# hack, so if I've made some ridiculously stupid mistake, please don't be overly harsh.

Thanks - I appreciate all help.

EDIT: I found the issue based on much of the assistance below.

For clarity, this is the entire function:

```
public int returnMaleBedTotal(string bedCollection) {
      // determine total number of male beds for a bay
      int bedCount = 0;
      if (bedCollection.Length > 0) {
        List<string> theBays = new List<string>(bedCollection.Split(new char[] { '@' }));

        // at this point we have the bays, so iterate them and extract the beds in the bays
        foreach (string bayBedCollection in theBays) {
          List<string> bayBeds = new List<string>(bayBedCollection.Split(new char[] { '|' }));

          // now we have the beds in the bay, so extract the bed properties and determine if the bed is male
          foreach(string bed in bayBeds) {
            string[] bedProperties = bed.Split(new char[] { '^' });
            if (bedProperties.Length > 1) {
              string genderCode = bedProperties[1];
              string bedStatus = bedProperties[2];
              if (genderCode == "M") {
                bedCount = bedCount + bayBeds.Count;
                break;

              }

            }

          }

        }

      } 

      return bedCount;

    }
```

This takes a collection in the form of a big string that looks like this:

```
100000^^3|100002^^1|100003^^3|100004^F^2|100005^^2@100006^^1|100007^^2|100008^M^2|100009^^1|100010^^3@100011^M^2|100012^M^2|100013^M^1|100014^M^2|100015^M^1@100016^F^1|100017^^1|100018^F^1|100019^^1|100020^^1
```

It then chops that up into units that look like this:

```
100000^^3|100002^^1|100003^^3|100004^F^2|100005^^2
```

Which it further parses to units like this:

```
100005^^2 or 100004^F^2
```

On occasion, during these iterations one of these units would come back malformed and would have a length of 1, so the attempt to get the an indice > 0 would fail.

By the way, this is an extension method inside a transform, and that's the reason for taking the initial collection as a big string.

Thanks to all who helped - sorry I can't choose more than one correct answer.

Comment: If you always access `bedProperties[1]`, then you should probably check for `bedProperties.Length > 1`.. couldn't it be possible that there is one bed in bayBeds that has only 1 property, and thus causes the exception?

Comment: I know you've got it in bold twice, but just to clarify - even when you know the array has more than 1 element you are getting an out of bounds exception?

Comment: @jball, the incoming strings look like this: 100000^^3 or 100004^F^2.  There are always 4 elements in each.

Comment: Quick correction, both of those will yield 3 element arrays. Is it safe to assume that none changes suggested in the answers below has solved your problem?

Comment: @jball yes, thanks for the correction - crazy I said that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (bedProperties.Length > 0)
```

Should really be:

```
if(bedProperties.Length > 1)
```

Because any string, when split, will return itself in a single element array. If any splitting actually took place, there would be two or more elements in the array.

Comment: You don't _really_ know that. In all fairness, I think it is slightly more plausible that the OP got zero-based indexing wrong (in contrast, it is hard to interpret an absolute quantity like `Length` wrong)

Comment: @sehe - Actually, I do. "If this instance does not contain any of the characters in separator, the returned array consists of a single element that contains this instance." ~ MSDN

Comment: @sehe - And, if it were in fact a zero based indexing issue, there would be no need for the if check to begin with since any call to split would have at least one element.

Comment: good observation. I still wouldn't be surprised if the OP meant to write `[0]` (and simply missed the fact that the conditional wasn't necessary)

Comment: The OP indicates that when checked directly, the array has a length of more than 1 (such as 3) which would indicate that the problem is not due to a single element array being returned.

Comment: Incoming strings look like this: 100000^^3, 100004^F^2, etc. There are always 4 elements, although each can be empty.  Does c# split omit the value in the new array if null?

Comment: [Just to explain Justin's answer] Accessing index 1 means that you have at least 2 items in bedProperties (at index 0 and 1). So, you need to check that the length/size of bedProperties has at least 2 items (greater than 1).

Comment: I updated the question above to provide detail for the answer.  This was just a bad data issue, and my own ignorance with respect to C#.  Thank you all very much - wish I could give props to everyone.

Answer (score 5):

You are encountering strings without `^` character:

Either fix the index:

```
if (bedProperties.Length > 0) {
  string genderCode = bedProperties[0]; // would take the **first** split element
```

or the condition:

```
if (bedProperties.Length > 1) {
  string genderCode = bedProperties[1]; // would take the **second** split element
```

(*Indices are zero-based* !!)

Comment: How does your first line correlate with the OP's statement that " I can modify to return bedProperties.Length and it will give me a value such as 3"?

Comment: @jball: why don't you ask the OP? Not with the code shown, that's for sure. Then again, the code shown doesn't return the bedProperties.Length either, so who knows what else was different around that time.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5421/discussion-between-sehe-and-jball)

Comment: Actually @Sehe you are correct as well - the data element was malformed and contained no split char.  I wish I could give you a correct on this, as well.  Both you and Justin essentially addressed the same issue, but he did it first, so I marked his answer correct.  Gave you a bump up though.

Comment: @ThomasWTupper: cheers, that's what we're here for! For the record, 'give a correct' is usually called 'accepting an answer' :)

Answer (score 0):

you test for `if (bedProperties.Length > 0)` but you are accessing `bedProperties[1];`
you should check for `if (bedProperties.Length > 1)` to make sure, index 1 is available.